# How to solve authorization with mixed users in REST API

Tags: c#, api, rest, authentication, authorization

We have a solution consisting of two internal web applications for maintaining different sets of data. Both of there websites accesses a .NET 4.6 REST API and the users are employees of the corporation.  All website users are members of website 1 or 2 groups in active directory and authorization can be done using AD and group membership.  Users of website 2 have some services that users of website 1 cannot access. So far, so good.  Windows auth, impersonation and all is fine.  Then comes the two cooperating businesses.  Business 1 shall only be allowed to make changes to 1 entity (we're using entity framework).  It is important that they cannot make calls to the API exposed to website 1 and 2.  Setting up trust between domain controllers is a no-go.  Business 2 exposes data of a very similar fashion as web site 1.  Their public facing portal has multiple million individual users.  It is unlikely to include other cooperating businesses.  Both businesses could be handed a certificated for authentication as this seems like a more secure approach than basic authentication even though it meets security minimum demands.  Should authorization be done in the controllers themselves, or in the services?

Please see the attached sketches.
[image: mixed mode authentication scenario]
**How would you go about securing the REST API given the description above?** I cannot find any good references of mixed mode authentication using Active Directory for authorization. One possibility would be to divide the REST API into an internal API, and an external API.  This way the exposed functionality would be greatly reduced, and we have a simpler, unified authorization regime for each REST API. This approach adds some overhead and possibly reduces maintainability a bit, as these two projects will share a lot of the underlying services, and we would also need to refactor some plumbing and helper classes into some kind of common library. Cooperating business nr 2 has agreed to hosting a reverse proxy for the external REST API if required.  Is is possible for us to create Active Directory user accounts for cooperating business 1 and 2. 
[image: REST API split in two]